# Show that the kernel of ψ is the image of ϕ of the kernel of ρ.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$, $H$, $K$ are groups and φ: $G$→$H$, ψ: $H$→$K$ and ρ: $G$→$K$ are homomorphisms such that

$ρ(g)=ψ(φ(g))$ for all $g ∈ G$

and φ is onto, show that the kernel of ψ is equivalent to the image of φ of the kernel of ρ.

I know that $ker(ψ)$={$h:H$| $ψ(h)=1$} and that $im(φ(ker(ρ)))$={$h$|$h=φ(g)$ where $ρ(g)=1$} but I'm not sure how to use any of there other information to get this equivalency. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align}\ker \psi &=\{ h \in H \mid \psi(h) = 1\} \\ &= \{\phi(g) \in H \mid g \in G, \psi(\phi(g)) = 1\} \\  &= \{\phi(g) \in H \mid g \in G, \rho(g) = 1\} \\ &= \phi(\ker \rho).\end{align}$$